# Print photo to physical printer with PHP

Tags: php, printing

Does anyone know how to print a bunch of photo file to the printer?

e.g. I need to print a photo files in a "/photos/" folder. Let say if there are 3 JPG files in that folder, I will print those 3 files to the printer.

What I have tried:

```
<?php

$fileList = glob('../files/*.jpeg');
foreach($fileList as $filename){
    if(is_file($filename)){
        copy($filename, "//localhost/epson");
    }
}
?>
```

But the result is, it prints the chunk data (or the 64 encode, I'm not sure but it was a weird character) rather than the photo itself.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: That was print to screen, mine is print to the printer physically

Answer (score -2):

### You create a port in Windows mapped to the USB port - in my case named terow. You then make your text file and copy it to the port.

```
$file =  "print.txt";

$handle = fopen($file, 'w');
$linefeed = chr(10);
$Data = "This is a test\n";
$Data .= "\n";
$Data .= "Line 1";
$Data .= "\n";
$Data .= "Line 2";
$Data .= $linefeed;
$Data .= $linefeed;

fwrite($handle, $Data);
fclose($handle);
copy($file, "//localhost/terow");
```

Comment: For text, I can print successfully, but cannot print image file